# static methods that manipulates Date. multi threading issue

Tags: java, multithreading, date, static, thread-safety

Friends,

I'm giving modified extract of my production code.

When running the following code, I'm getting "TestDateProblem: Problem with getYear method" though I'm executing the `getDateEndOfDay` by passing auditdate1.

I couldn't really solve this issue as the date is going correctly and I could see this in the logger in the catch block of my production code. I badly need your help.

This `getDateEndOfDay` method is called from many public methods and it may be possible that multiple threads are calling these static methods at the same time.

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.Date;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


public class TestDateProblem {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * This is the date format that is mostly used. Logger shows this kind
         * of date during Exception.
         */
        String auditdate1 = "2011-12-27";
        // Rarely sent this way.
        String auditdate2 = "27-12-2011";
        /*
         * We don't send this way but I'm sure the problem occurs if the date goes this
         * way. As far as the inputs are concerned, it doesn't go like this.
         */
        String auditdate3 = "27-2011-12";

        try {

            System.out.println("Result1:" + getDateEndOfDay(auditdate1));

            System.out.println("Result2:" + getDateEndOfDay(auditdate2));
            // simulating problem?
            System.out.println("Result3:" + getDateEndOfDay(auditdate3));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("auditdate1:" + auditdate1);
        }
    }

    /*
     * This getDateEndOfDay(.) method is called from many public methods and it
     * may be possible that multiple threads are calling these static methods at
     * the same time.
     */
    public static Date getDateEndOfDay(String dateparam) throws Exception {
        String separator = "/";
        dateparam = dateparam.replace("-", separator);
        String[] strP = dateparam.split(separator);
        Integer year = getYear(strP);
        Integer month = getMonth(strP);
        Integer day = getDay(strP);
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, day, 23,
                59, 00);

        return cal.getTime();
    }

    private static Integer getYear(String[] dateComponents) throws Exception {
        if (dateComponents.length != 3) {
            return 1900;
        }
        System.out
                .println("dateComponents::" + Arrays.toString(dateComponents));

        Integer val1 = Integer
                .valueOf(dateComponents[0].startsWith("0") ? dateComponents[0]
                        .substring(1) : dateComponents[0]);
        Integer val2 = Integer
                .valueOf(dateComponents[2].startsWith("0") ? dateComponents[2]
                        .substring(1) : dateComponents[2]);
        if (val1 > 1900) {
            return val1;
        } else if (val2 > 1900) {
            return val2;
        } else {
            // Original code throws exception instead of printing to console.
            System.out.println("TestDateProblem: Problem with getYear method.");
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    private static Integer getDay(String[] dateComponents) {
        if (dateComponents.length != 3) {
            return -1;
        }

        Integer val1 = Integer
                .valueOf(dateComponents[0].startsWith("0") ? dateComponents[1]
                        .substring(1) : dateComponents[0]);
        Integer val2 = Integer
                .valueOf(dateComponents[2].startsWith("0") ? dateComponents[1]
                        .substring(1) : dateComponents[2]);

        if (val1 <= 31) {
            return val1;
        } else if (val2 <= 31) {
            return val2;
        } else {
            System.out.println("TestDateProblem: Problem with getDay method.");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private static Integer getMonth(String[] dateComponents) {
        if (dateComponents.length != 3) {
            return 0;
        }

        Integer val1 = Integer
                .valueOf(dateComponents[1].startsWith("0") ? dateComponents[1]
                        .substring(1) : dateComponents[1]);

        if (val1 <= 12 && val1 >= 1) {
            return val1;
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("TestDateProblem:: Problem with getMonth method");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It certainly has a lot of pointless code which makes it hard to read. My favourite is `Integer val1 = Integer
                .valueOf(dateComponents[0].startsWith("0") ? dateComponents[0]
                        .substring(1) : dateComponents[0])` I would suggest you add unit tests and use the debugger for failing cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not written the original code. I'm trying to fix the production bug which occurs only sometimes. So, this is not reproducable always so I was suspecting some threading issue. This problem occurs sometimes when we have some of our new batches running.

Comment: Can you change the error message to display the full input of what is invalid?  That way you can see that when you use that invalid input you will get the same error every time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can tell you that they have written this code to accept both the formats "yyyy/mm/dd" and "dd/mm/yyy" from the user and the day can come as '05' or '5' so is the reason we have some code on substring. The logger in catch block shows inputs: valid date (2011-12-6) and valid format (yyyy-mm-dd). This production bug occurs only sometimes. So, this is not reproducable always; So I was suspecting some threading issue. This problem occurs sometimes when we have some of our new batches running.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to believe that there are any thread-safety problems in this code.  It has no static variables or other means by which non-local variable are manipulated.  The only place where code which could even possibly be non-threadsafe is called is when you create a new GregorianCalendar object, but nothing in that documentation suggests that it wouldn't be threadsafe, so I think that's highly unlikely.

Also, isn't there already date-parsing stuff in Java?  Why not just use java.text.SimpleDateFormat's parse method?  Wouldn't that be much easier than all this?

Comment: Hi Irwin, Appreciate your answer. I have not written the original code.  They have written this code to accept both the formats "yyyy/mm/dd" and "dd/mm/yyy" from the user and the day can come as '05' or '5' so is the reason we have some code on substring. The logger in our catch block shows inputs : date (2011-12-6) and format (yyyy-mm-dd). I'm actually trying to fix the production bug which occurs only sometimes. So, this is not reproducable always so I was suspecting some threading issue. This problem occurs sometimes when we have some of our new batches running. Please help me.

Comment: I can't really help without knowing what actual data is causing the problem.  I can tell you, though, with very strong certainty that it is not a threading issue.

Comment: Hi Irwin, The date that is going into the function is "2011-12-6". And if it goes like this, it shouldn't cause any issue in the sample program that I have given here, but in production it throws the exception mentioned only sometimes. Please let me know what data you would like to know?

Comment: Well, what I would really like to know is what's different in the cases where it does throw the exception from times where it doesn't.  It is not possible that this is a threading issue because you don't use any potentially non-threadsafe code at any point prior to the error message.

Comment: So either 1) there's something different about the input string sometimes 2) there's something different between the way the code is getting called in this sample from how it's getting called in the production code which matters in this case 3) you've got a bug in your JVM 4) you've got a bug in your compiler 5) you've got a memory error on your production server or 6) you've got a processor bug on your production server.  One of those six things must be true.  I don't know which one, but it's got to be one of those.

Comment: Well, I have put additional logger statements in place so once we move this code to production and if this issue occurs again, we can get additional data on inputs. I shall get in touch with you when this happens. Thanks a ton for your willingness to help.

Answer (score 2):

While the code is needlessly verbose, it is also reasonably clear.  The problem you have is that its trying to work out whether the date is in yyyy/mm/dd format or dd/mm/yyyy format, however if you give it sometime like yy/mm/dd format it can't work out what it is and gives the error you see.

Stepping through the code with a debugger would confirm this.

I would read this comment again as it explains the problem

```
* We don't send this way but the problem occurs if the date goes this
* way.
```

You are giving it an invalid formatted date and it is rightly rejecting it because it doesn't know how to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not written the original code. But I can tell you that they have written this code to accept both the formats "yyyy/mm/dd" and "dd/mm/yyy" from the user and the day can come as '05' or '5' so is the reason we have some code on substring. The logger shows the valid date (2011-12-6) and valid format (yyyy-mm-dd). I'm actually trying to fix the production bug which occurs only sometimes. So, this is not reproducable always so I was suspecting some threading issue. This problem occurs sometimes when we have some of our new batches running.

Comment: If you display the string or year which is failing, as I suggested you will be able to see if its corrupt and should have been successful. From the code, it doesn't appear to be a threading issue in this code, but could be a thread issue in code which call this.  BTW if you do `Integer.parseInt("05")` you get and int `5` rather than an `Integer` object so the substring is redundant.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. It was very old code written by some body else. I will improve it.

Comment: If you do have a thread safety issue in the calling code, you might see two dates over the top of each other like `2020111//0505//3131` or `22001111//0055//3311` This is why printing out bad input is so useful.

Comment: Thanks Peter. In the existing code, they are printing the input NOT at the place where it's causing/throwing the problem but at the place where it's catching the thrown problem. I've already added some logger to capture the input at the place where the problem is occurred but we are yet to see this problem in Production. As I told earlier, we couldn't reproduce this problem always.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with auditdate3, not with auditdate1.
You pass 27-2011-12 as a date and try to extract a year. You check for a year at first and the last components of the date, but 27 and 12 are not a valid year. That's why you have an Exception. You should run your code in debugger.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer. I'm sorry for the confusion. In the actual production code, I could see only auditdate1 with the format yyyy-mm-dd as confirmed by the logger message in catch block. I just mentioned auditdate3 just to say that this way we are sure to get the problem. I was wondering if threads can modify the object and cause this kind of problem?